# Cosa vuol dire "castigato" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Fosforo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Pochi giorni dopo la mia assunzione, il Commendatore mi chiamò in Direzione, ed in quella occasione notai che le foto con la barca a vela, del resto assai **castigate**, c’erano proprio.

Queste fotografie si erano menzionate prima in questo passaggio, che narra le spiegazioni  che gli fa Giulia, un'amica di Levi, lavoratrice nell'industria dove lui era stato appena assunto:

> Il Commendatore era il padrone, benché sottoposto ad oscuri altri padroni di Basilea: tuttavia chi comandava era la Loredana (e me la indicò dalla finestra nel cortile: alta, bruna, formosa, volgarotta, un po’ sfiorita), che era la sua segretaria e la sua amante. Avevano una villa sul lago, e lui, «che era vecchio ma mandrillo», la portava in barca a vela: c’erano delle foto in Direzione, non le avevo viste?

Non capisco cosa vuol dire che le foto erano "castigate". Ho cercato "castigato" in parecchi dizionari, tra i quali il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/castigato) e il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000864.jpg), ma non mi sembra che le diverse accezioni che ho trovato possano avere senso nel contesto del testo. Qualcuno di voi saprebbe spiegarmi che significa?

Comment: Mi sembra che sia semplicemente il significato 2 del Treccani, o il 4 del GDLI. Perché ti sembra che non abbia senso nel contesto?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni:  Fotografie ammonite o riprese? Morigerate?
Forse morigerate ha senso, non so... Significherebbe che tutte le persone che appaiono hanno aspetto morigerato, non licenzioso?

Comment: Sì, esattamente.

Comment: Dal contesto sembra che il narratore sottolinei che nelle foto, per esempio, la segretaria non indossa un costume particolarmente succinto. Il tizio è un “mandrillo” ma non mostra l'amante mezza nuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il significato è proprio quello che hai dedotto: le persone che appaiono nella foto hanno aspetto morigerato, non licenzioso.

Ovvero quello che si trova [nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/castigato) (o del punto 4 nel link che hai inserito)

> 2. Morigerato, che segue le leggi della morale e della convenienza: *vita c.; costumi castigati; abito c., scollatura castigata.*

Si tratta della figura retorica della [metonimia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonimia), in cui un termine (le persone ritratte nella foto) viene sostituito con l'oggetto correlato (la foto stessa).

Il commento di @DaG aiuta a inquadrare il contesto: il personaggio «che era vecchio ma mandrillo» ha delle foto dell'amante (o delle amanti) in barca a vela, dove appaiono in modo morigerato (non licenzioso).