# Cosa significa "equipaggio" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Fosforo* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Circolare per Milano in bicicletta non aveva allora nulla di temerario, e portare un passeggero in canna, in tempi di bombe e di sfollamenti, era poco meno che normale: qualche volta, specie se di notte, accadeva che estranei domandassero questo servizio, e che per un trasporto da un capo all’altro della città ti ricompensassero con quattro o cinque lire. Ma Giulia, già di regola piuttosto irrequieta, quella sera comprometteva la stabilità dell’**equipaggio**: stringeva convulsamente il manubrio contrastando la guida, cambiava di scatto posizione, illustrava il suo discorso con gesti violenti delle mani e del capo che spostavano in modo imprevedibile il nostro comune baricentro.

Non capisco il significato di "equipaggio" in questo testo. Ho cercato alla voce "equipaggio" di parecchi dizionari, tra i quali il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/equipaggio) e il *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000225.jpg)] e [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI05/00000226.jpg)]), ma non riesco a vedere nessuna accezione che possa avere senso nel contesto del brano. Sapreste spiegare cosa vuol dire che Giulia "comprometteva la stabilità dell’equipaggio"? Forse che comprometteva la stabilità delle due persone che viaggiavano sulla bicicletta  (lei stessa e Primo Levi)?

Come una risorsa in più per tentare di capire questa espressione, ho cercato la traduzione del libro allo spagnolo di Carmen Martín Gaite e ho visto che ha reso la frase in cui appare in questo modo:

> Pero Giulia, ya más bien inquieta de por sí, aquella tarde ponía en un brete la estabilidad del vehículo

Cioè, ha tradotto "la stabilità dell’equipaggio" come "la estabilidad del vehículo" e il resto della frase è molto fedele all'originale. "Vehículo" significa "veicolo", ma nelle diverse accezioni di "equipaggio" che ho trovato sui dizionari non ho visto nessuna che sia "veicolo" (questo mi fa sospettare che probabilmente la traduzione non fosse facile od ovvia per Martín Gaite).

Comment: Già, proprio così, l'equipaggio erano le persone a bordo della bici. Per te è un uso troppo disinvolto o scherzoso del termine?

Comment: Il senso  è quello del punto 3b di Treccani, usato  per estensione in riferimento a chi stava sopra la bicicletta.

Comment: Può darsi che la risposta a questa domanda sia un'ovvietà per un madrelingua (considerata persino off-topic?), ma vi posso assicurare che per me non lo è. Ho visto che la traduzione del libro allo spagnolo di Carmen Martín Gaite si trova in parecchie biblioteche di Barcellona. Adesso che molte di queste biblioteche sono di nuovo aperte, per curiosità, forse cercherò di  dare un'occhiata per vedere come l'ha tradotto lei.

Comment: Su [questo link](https://books.google.es/books?redir_esc=y&hl=it&id=ccT4AgAAQBAJ&q=%C3%A9poca#v=snippet&q=Barbabram%C3%ADn&f=false) si può leggere un pezzo di questa traduzione: la mia impressione è che cerca di essere abbastanza fedele all'originale.

Comment: Non saprei dire riguardo la traduzione in spagnolo, comunque il senso in italiano è abbastanza intuitivo. Nella frase in questione, come notato, il termine è usato per estensione. Spero ti sia chiaro ora.

Comment: Ho cercato la traduzione e ho aggiunto quello che ho trovato alla domanda. Se la traduzione non era ovvia per Carmen Martín Gaite, non capisco perché dovrebbe esserlo per me. Martín Gaite era scrittrice e tradutrice: aveva tradotto parecchi libri dall'italiano, dal francese, dal portoghese e dall'inglese. Qualche sua traduzione ha guadagnato un [premio importante](https://elpais.com/diario/2000/11/16/cultura/974329203_850215.html) per la sua qualità.

Comment: Le sue traduzioni sono studiate a fondo in questo [recente articolo di M. Uberti-Bona](https://www.academia.edu/41627489/Geograf%C3%ADas_del_di%C3%A1logo_La_traducci%C3%B3n_en_la_obra_de_Carmen_Mart%C3%ADn_Gaite), del Dipartimento di Lingue e Letterature Straniere dell'Università di Milano.

Comment: Per curiosità, ho cercato anche come aveva tradotto qualche altra espressione del libro sulla quale ho posto una domanda: non sempre la sua traduzione corrisponde a quello che mi si è detto nella risposta (un esempio è [questa domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/13092)). Credo che il significato di queste espressioni  non fosse tanto facile per Martín Gaite e allora non capisco perché dovrebbe esserlo per me o perché una domanda a proposito non ha senso o interesse o quello che sia.

Comment: Evidentemente il termine equipaggio non è usato in spagnolo nelle stesse accezioni dell’ italiano. Lei ha tradotto la stabilità del “veicolo” mentre nell’originale si parla della stabilità dell’equipaggio ossia delle persone che stanno sul veicolo. Il senso non è molto diverso. Btw io non ho down votato ne close votato la tua domanda.

Comment: Sì, @Hachi, ma la mia impressione leggendo la traduzione di Martín Gaite è che per lei non era stato evidente che si trattasse di un'allusione scherzosa all'accezione 3.b del Treccani. Se lo fosse stato, avrebbe tradotto l'espressione in un altro modo. Per esempio, avrebbe potuto renderla "la estabilidad de los pasajeros" o "la estabilidad de la tripulación".

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica:  Se il significato è chiarissimo, eccetto per me (per questa ragione ho posto la domanda) e molto probabilmente per Martín Gaite, non capisco perché la domanda dovrebbe essere "opinion-based" (e quindi "off-topic"). Non capisco neanche perché non ha nessuna risposta. La informazione che ho aggiunto sulla traduzione risponde al fatto che il sito richiede "provide details and any research" quando si pone una domanda (siccome per il momento non ha ricevuto nessuna risposta, cercare la traduzione era per me una risorsa in più per cercare di capire il significato).

Comment: @Charo - la traduttrice è sicuramente in gamba, infatti la sua traduzione della frase è molto vicino all’origine  nel senso. Ovviamente non ha potuto fare una traduzione letterale in quanto il termine spagnolo che mi sembra sia  “tripulation” non viene usato in questa accezione  come  in italiano. Detto questo il senso mi sembra chiaro. Per equipaggio si intende  le persone  che stavano sopra la bicicletta. Ne più ne meno.

Comment: Un dubbio mi rimane a questo punto, se come dici,  la traduttrice avesse   tradotto   la frase “la estabilidad de la tripulation”, uno spagnolo avrebbe capito il senso?

Comment: Visto che tradurre non significa tradurre parola per parola (_Non verbum e verbo, sed sensum de sensu_, diceva Gerolamo), fino a prova contraria possiamo ritenere che si tratti di una scelta conscia della traduttrice. Ciò detto, mi resta la curiosità su come abbia reso le foto castigate...

Comment: @DaG: Rende la frase in questo modo: «Pocos días después de mi admisión, el Commendatore me llamó al despacho de la Dirección, y en aquella ocasión me di cuenta de que las fotos con el barco de vela, bastante estropeadas por cierto, estaban realmente allí». Traduce «assai castigate» come «bastante estropeadas» e il resto è molto fedele all'orginale. «Estropeadas» significa mal ridotte, in cattivo stato, danneggiate, sciupate.

Comment: @Charo - se traduce castigate col termine che dici, direi che non è una buona traduzione in questo caso. E in effetti https://www.grandidizionari.it/Dizionario_Spagnolo-Italiano/parola/e/estropeado.aspx?query=estropeado

Comment: @Hachi, stai spiegando il significato di una parola spagnola a Charo, che è spagnola e che l'ha già spiegato a noi?

Comment: @DaG - scusa ho fatto un double-check, mi sembrava sembrava  che castigato fosse stato tradotto come danneggiato, sciupato.

Comment: @Hachi. Dovrebbe essere proprio così, infatti. Per citare Charo: “Traduce «assai castigate» come «bastante estropeadas» e il resto è molto fedele all'orginale. «Estropeadas» significa mal ridotte, in cattivo stato, danneggiate, sciupate.”

Comment: @Charo - si ma mi sembra che il senso di foto castigate si riferisca a “castigato” in senso morale  (come suggerisce la risposta) mentre esptrooeadas mi sembra si riferisca a caratteristiche fisiche (da cui il  mio double-check).

Comment: @Hachi: Non ho detto che mi sembri una buona traduzione, semplicemente che questo mi fa pensare quello che ho spiegato in [quest'altro commento](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/13107/cosa-significa-equipaggio-in-questo-passaggio#comment31267_13107).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

È possibile che la traduttrice non abbia capito il senso di *equipaggio* e sia andata *ad sensum*. Oppure che l'abbia capito e abbia consapevolmente deciso per una soluzione diversa da *tripulación* perché in spagnolo non avrebbe reso l'idea: su questo passo perché non conosco l'uso del termine.

L'equipaggio di una nave o altro veicolo consiste delle persone che ne rendono possibile e sicuro il movimento. Su una nave, i marinai, i motoristi, gli ufficiali e così via, anche se *equipaggio*, in senso stretto, può non comprendere gli ufficiali. Su una barca a remi, i rematori. Su un treno, i macchinisti e il personale viaggiante.

In senso lato (e magari scherzoso), chi sia sul veicolo. Chi abbia provato a trasportare un passeggero sulla canna di una bicicletta, sa che il passeggero non deve agire sul manubrio, ma al più tenerci appoggiate le mani senza spingere da un lato o dall'altro per non turbare il già precario equilibrio dovuto all'asimmetria causata dalle gambe del passeggero. Un movimento improvviso delle gambe può infatti avere effetti indesiderati: il moto della bicicletta si basa sulla conservazione del momento angolare e sull'effetto giroscopico che ne è la conseguenza. Ancora peggio se il passeggero spinge il manubrio.

Levi dice *equipaggio* e non *veicolo*, forse per riferirsi proprio alla stabilità delle due persone, non solo riguardo alla marcia della bicicletta, già vacillante a cause della situazione di bombe e sfollamenti. Speculazione? Non ne sono sicuro. Oppure voleva paragonare la bicicletta a una barca a remi che fila dritta solo se l'equipaggio rema con coordinazione.

<sub>Il mio fratellino (nove anni meno di me) era molto attento quando lo portavo così alla palestra nel pomeriggio (non distante) o al palazzetto dello sport per la partita di basket (un paio di chilometri) e non abbiamo mai rischiato gravi incidenti. Pensare di fare la stessa strada al giorno d'oggi mi fa venire i brividi. Allora non c'erano piste ciclabili, ma in tanti anni di bici ho avuto solo un incidente, quando un tale a piedi mi investì sbucando di corsa da un portico. Si fece più male lui.</sub>

Comment: Non ha veramente importanza, ma il concetto che hai descritto in spagnolo si chiama proprio "tripulación": vedi la [definizione del dizionario della Real Academia Española](https://dle.rae.es/tripulaci%C3%B3n?m=form).

Comment: @Charo Certo, ma non so se si usa in senso figurato.

Comment: egreg e @Hachi: Di solito non si usa in senso figurato (perlomeno che io sappia), ma se la tradutrice avesse reso l'espressione "la estabilidad de la tripulación" si avrebbe capito perfettamente, soprattutto perché, come potete vedere nel dizionario "tripulación" ha unicamente il significato di "insieme di persone a bordo di...", mentre invece la voce "equipaggio" ha otto punti diversi sul GDLI.

Comment: A dire il vero, i commenti alla domanda mi hanno convinta della risposta.

Comment: @Charo - bene, mi fa piacere che ti siano serviti per chiarire questo punto. Ma non è che usare il GDLI ti crei un po’ di confusione? A mio modesto avviso, visto il tipo di domande che generalmente fai, un buon dizionario di Italiano corrente sarebbe di maggior aiuto. IMMO

Comment: @Hachi: Non guardo mai soltanto il GDLI, e non consulto mai il GDLI per primo, ma ho scoperto che molti dei significati che cerco si trovano soltanto sul GDLI (e di tanto in tanto succede che la stessa frase che tento di capire si trova proprio sul GDLI come esempio di uso del termine o espressione: dal *Sistema periodico* ne ho trovate parecchie). Il GDLI è in rete soltanto dal maggio 2019 (ho saputo della sua esistenza il 13 maggio grazie a DaG) e io stessa sono stata capace di trovare sul GDLI la risposta a alcune domande mie (e persino di qualche altro utente) precedenti a questa data.

Answer (score 1):

Un'interpretazione alternativa, che trovo ancora più divertente, è che con *equipaggio* Levi intendesse solo sé stesso, relegando Giulia al ruolo di semplice passeggero poco osservante delle regole di bordo. Questa cosa promuoverebbe la bicicletta, mezzo facile da guidare, a veicolo più complesso, con separazione netta tra equipaggio e passeggeri.

Comment: In effetti, suona sensato! Chissà se era quello che aveva in mente Levi.